# Flask redirect to url and pass query strings

Tags: python, flask

I have a view that is defined like such:

```
@views.route('/issues')
def show_view():
    action = request.args.get('action')
method = getattr(process_routes, action)
return method(request.args)
```

in my process_routes module, I would like to call this method, and pass query string values. I have the following code:

```
return redirect(url_for('views.show_view', action='create_or_update_success'))
```

I have a function in process_routes named create_or_update_success

I am getting

```
BuildError: ('views.show_view', {'action': 'create_or_update_success'}, None)
```

views is a blueprint. I can successfully call

```
/issues?action=create_or_update_success
```

In my browser.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Apparently `url_for()` cannot find the `views.show_view` registration. Are you sure your `views` Blueprint uses the name `views` when registered with your `Flask` object?

Comment: Or is `views` perhaps your `Flask` object itself?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I am sure that is the case. I have `views = Blueprint(__name__, __name__)`. The app object is named `app`

Comment: `__name__` is the name of the current module, so your `Blueprint` object is probably not named `views`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry, I was trying to make it less confusing and simplify my problem. My routes are defined in views.py, and the actual blueprint is defined as `views_blueprint = Blueprint(__name__, __name__)`. I am sorry if this was confusing, I was trying to make it easier to see what my problem is. I am actually calling `views_blueprint.show_view`, I also tried to call `views.show_view`. My app is defined in `main.py`, I import the `views_blueprint` from `views.py` and do `app.register_blueprint(views_blueprint)` in `main.py`.

Comment: I suspect that `views.py` is a module in a *package*, in which case `__name__` will contain the full path. Don't use `__name__` as the first argument, give it a string literal instead so you can be sure of its value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part, `views.`, has to reflect the first argument you give to your `Blueprint()` object exactly.

Don't be tempted to set that first argument to `__name__`, as that is likely to contain the full path of the module when inside a package. In your case I suspect that to be `some_package.views` rather than just `views`.

Use a string literal for the `Blueprint()` first argument instead:

```
views_blueprint = Blueprint('views', __name__)
```

so you can refer to `url_for('views.show_view')` without getting build errors.